# Java create Customer function gives random values

Tags: java, maven, listener

I'm working on a insert customers in system project. It is working in tomcat, and is a maven project. Since I started a new project; some things work; some things don't. I made a createCustomer function:

```
public static Customer createCustomer(String name){
    if (allCustomers.stream().noneMatch(e->e.getName().equals(name))) {
        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(name);
        allCustomers.add(newCustomer);
        return newCustomer;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

When I run my BootupListener; I entered:

```
    Customer.createCustomer("Maikol");
    Customer.createCustomer("Henk");
    nl.hu.bep.model.Customer.createCustomer("Sjon");

    System.out.println(Customer.getAllCustomers());
    System.out.println(Customer.getCustomer(1));
    System.out.println(Customer.getCustomerById(1));
```

Which strangely gives the prints:

[nl.hu.bep.model.Customer@94bfdfef, nl.hu.bep.model.Customer@4263369, nl.hu.bep.model.Customer@4c37fee]
nl.hu.bep.model.Customer@94bfdfef
nl.hu.bep.model.Customer@94bfdfef

nl.hu.bep is my package tag, and Customer is the class where createcustomer is located.
Why does it not work?

Comment: Have you overriden the `toString` method of `Customer` class ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it gives different outputs.

All customers with the object specifiers are, respectively, -> `94bfdfef, 4263369, 4c37fee`

As far as we know, the last 2 outputs show conspicuously that both are involved in the `Customers` maintained.

The issue(if it is a issue), imho, stems from the data structure hold the users. There is no order for `Set` data structure, for instance. If you map(using `HashMap`) the ids with the customer numbers, there is still no oder guarantee at all that of data structure.

Answer (score 1):

When you print a collection, it prints `[`, then a comma separated list of all the items inside, and then `]`. And to print 'an item', it invokes that item's `toString()` method (unless it is null, then it prints `null`).

The `toString()` in java.lang.Object has absolutely no idea what to do, so it just prints the name of the type, followed by an `@`, followed by the system identity hashcode, which is meaningless, and will change on every JVM invocation.

The solution is to implement toString methods. Your Customer method SHOULD be:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    // other fields here

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Customer: " + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the answer is the OP's intent.